# What side mounting screws for old electrical box

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I'm trying to mount a ceiling fan on an older electrical box... I need to buy some longer screws so it will fit, does anyone know what the standard size screw would be for the ones in the corner ? Please se image .[image]

Comment: You are looking for a #8 I believe. In your Hardware store pick up a box carry it to the screw aisle and verify to be sure it could be #6 neither are expensive .50 for a pack each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely 8-32, possibly 6-32.   Watch out, 8-32 is fine thread.

The -32 is intentional as it assures enough thread engagement.

Make sure you are hanging your fan by more than just a couple #8 screws!

Comment: If it's confusing, buy a box and use the screws from that box.